# How to change column names of many dataframes in R?

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to make the same changes to the column names of many dataframes. Here's an example:

```
ChangeNames <- function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- toupper(colnames(x))
  colnames(x) <- str_replace_all(colnames(x), pattern = "_", replacement = ".")
  return(x)
}

files <- list(mtcars, nycflights13::flights, nycflights13::airports)
lapply(files, ChangeNames)
```

I know that lapply only changes a copy. How do I change the underlying dataframe? I want to still use each dataframe separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a named list, apply the function and use `list2env` to reflect those changes in the original dataframes.

```
library(nycflights13)

files <- dplyr::lst(mtcars, flights, airports)
result <- lapply(files, ChangeNames)
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but I get the following error message: 
"Error in list2env(result, .GlobalEnv): 
names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x"

Comment: This works fine with the example you have shared. Are you using it in the same way as in my answer? Are you using this on some different data? What does `names(files)` return?

Comment: Thank you! You're right, sorry I must have mistyped a bit of your code. It works like a charm!